# angular2-modal: "permission denied to access property rejection"

Tags: javascript, angular

while using angular2-modal in my amgular2seedadvanced app gettiong an error

Error: Permission denied to access property "rejection"

I seen this question has been asked before but, in my case i couldn't solve this issue. I am following [this](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal/blob/master/QUICKTHROUGH.md).

package.json

```
"angular2-modal": "^2.0.2"
```

system-config.js

```
'angular2-modal': 'node_modules/angular2-modal/bundles/angular2-modal.umd.js',
  'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap': 'node_modules/angular2-modal/bundles/angular2-modal.bootstrap.umd.js'
packages: {
 'angular2-modal': {
    main: './index',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap': {
    main: 'index.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
}
```

component.ts

```
import { Modal } from 'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap';

@BaseComponent({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'demo-list',
templateUrl: './list.component.html',
styleUrls: ['list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent {

constructor(public modal: Modal) {}

addUser() {
        this.modal.alert()
        .title('Hello World')
        .body('In Angular 2')
        .open();
    }    
};
```

list.component.html

```
<div>
    <h4>Users
    <button type="button" style="float: right;" (click)="addUser()">Add</button>
    </h4>
    <md-card>
        Basic card.
    </md-card>
</div>
```

while clicking add button modal will not displayed instead getting this error. How can i solve this issue?

Comment: your component.ts doesn't have an `export`, so that `addUser()` function is private, and can't be seen in order to be bound by angular.

Comment: in fact, that component is missing *quite a bit* of what it needs to be a proper component.

Comment: my list.component is added

Comment: you *still* don't have an `export`.  Your component won't compile.

Comment: list.component.ts updated

Comment: This error happened the same to me in Firefox 50 because of Angular 2 template syntax error. Try debugging in Chrome browser and you would see the error.